# How to uninstall my app from Android emulator on a mac 10.7.4

Tags: android, emulation, uninstallation

I am looking for the correct method to uninstall my app from the Android emulator on a mac book pro. The instructions I see are for Windows OS.

Looking for steps to recreate the Reset Simulator process in Xcode.

Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fully reset a Android emulator:

- Open the Android AVD manager.
- Start the emulator you want to reset.
- Check the "Wipe user data" box.
- Click Launch.

If you just want to remove a application:

- Start the emulator.
- Open the Android settings app
- Select "Applications" (Called "Apps" on Android 4.0 or higher)
- Select "Manage Applications" (Only on Android 3.2 or lower)
- Select the application you want to uninstall
- Click "Uninstall"

Comment: Thank you Leon for taking the time to answer the question. That worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you, although that was obvious. Is there a way to do it via command line itself?

Comment: It's possible using the `adb uninstall <package name>` command when the emulator is running.